# Sails.js sockets communication in Swift?

Tags: swift, sails.js

Is there any library to connect through sockets to a sails.js (socket.io) based website in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Socket.IO-client for iOS/OS X.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift